# How to add totals rows to reactable table after every seven days in R?

Tags: r, reactable

I'd like to add some rows to my `reactable` table which show the column totals or averages over a 7-day period. In my real data, I have both a date (see `df$date` below) and a day (`df$day`) column, and I'd like to calculate the total or average (depending on the variable) for a Monday-Sunday period. Issue is, I can't just add these "totals" rows after every 7 rows in my data as the number of entries per Monday-Sunday will vary. For example, there's three entries for one 7-day period below and four for another. I'd like to get the total for some columns, such as `df$var1` and the average for others `df$var2` (my real data has more columns compared to the example below). Essentially, I'd like my `reactable` table to look something like this...

[image]

It would also be preferable to have these "totals" rows in bold text with the cell backgrounds filled with a different colour to stand out, such as light red. Note that my example image below takes the total for `df$var1` and the average for `df$var2`. My example code is below, so any assistance tackling this will be appreciated.

```
library(reactable)

set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(
  date = c("09/09/2023", "07/09/2023", "05/09/2023", "02/09/2023",
            "31/08/2023", "29/08/2023", "28/03/2023"),
  day = c("Saturday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Saturday", "Thursday",
          "Tuesday", "Monday"),
  var1 = round(rnorm(7, 5000, 1000)),
  var2 = round(rnorm(7, 1000, 500))
  )

reactable(df,
          striped = TRUE,
          defaultColDef = colDef(
            align = "center"),
          columns = list(
            day = colDef(show = FALSE)
            )
          )
```